# I need a way to change the image displayed by an ImageView in Android Studio (in Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, imageview, android-imageview

I need to change an ImageView in Android Studio to display a different image (while the program is running). I didn't find a way to accomplish this in Kotlin yet. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reference to the ImageView (for example, using ViewBinding or `findViewById`), then you can use the method `setImageResource`, as stated in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/ImageView#setimageresource)

Example:

```kotlin
// declare ImageView reference
var myImageView: ImageView

// in onCreate
myImageView = findViewById(R.id.myImageView)

// change image
myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageName)
```